# Handling textbox event in one Handler

Tags: vb.net

I do know how to handle event of textboxes in my form. But want to make this code shorter. Let me stop writing every time txtDraw1,2,3,4,5 in the handler, and generally put txtDraw with the values from 1 to 8. ie in handles to contain each txtDraw, without writing them manually.

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtDrawA1.TextChanged, txtDrawA2.TextChanged, txtDrawA3.TextChanged, txtDrawA4.TextChanged, txtDrawA5.TextChanged, txtDrawA6.TextChanged, txtDrawA7.TextChanged, txtDrawA8.TextChanged, txtDrawB1.TextChanged, txtDrawB2.TextChanged, txtDrawB3.TextChanged, txtDrawB4.TextChanged, txtDrawB5.TextChanged, txtDrawB6.TextChanged, txtDrawB7.TextChanged, txtDrawB8.TextChanged, txtDrawC1.TextChanged, txtDrawC2.TextChanged, txtDrawC3.TextChanged, txtDrawC4.TextChanged, txtDrawC5.TextChanged, txtDrawC6.TextChanged, txtDrawC7.TextChanged, txtDrawC8.TextChanged, txtDrawD1.TextChanged, txtDrawD2.TextChanged, txtDrawD3.TextChanged, txtDrawD4.TextChanged, txtDrawD5.TextChanged, txtDrawD6.TextChanged, txtDrawD7.TextChanged, txtDrawD8.TextChanged, txtDrawE1.TextChanged, txtDrawE2.TextChanged, txtDrawE3.TextChanged, txtDrawE4.TextChanged, txtDrawE5.TextChanged, txtDrawE6.TextChanged, txtDrawE7.TextChanged, txtDrawE8.TextChanged, txtDrawF1.TextChanged, txtDrawF2.TextChanged, txtDrawF3.TextChanged, txtDrawF4.TextChanged, txtDrawF5.TextChanged, txtDrawF6.TextChanged, txtDrawF7.TextChanged, txtDrawF8.TextChanged, txtDrawG1.TextChanged, txtDrawG2.TextChanged, txtDrawG3.TextChanged, txtDrawG4.TextChanged, txtDrawG5.TextChanged, txtDrawG6.TextChanged, txtDrawG6.TextChanged, txtDrawG7.TextChanged, txtDrawG8.TextChanged, txtDrawH1.TextChanged, txtDrawH2.TextChanged, txtDrawH3.TextChanged, txtDrawH4.TextChanged, txtDrawH5.TextChanged, txtDrawH6.TextChanged, txtDrawH7.TextChanged, txtDrawH8.TextChanged, txtDrawI1.TextChanged, txtDrawI2.TextChanged, txtDrawI3.TextChanged, txtDrawI4.TextChanged, txtDrawI5.TextChanged, txtDrawI6.TextChanged, txtDrawI7.TextChanged, txtDrawI8.TextChanged
    SetTextBoxColor(DirectCast(sender, TextBox))
End Sub
Sub SetTextBoxColor(ByVal txt As TextBox)
    Select Case txt.Text
        Case "1"
            txt.BackColor = Color.DarkSalmon
        Case "2"
            txt.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        Case "3"
            txt.BackColor = Color.DimGray
        Case "4"
            txt.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
        Case "5"
            txt.BackColor = Color.Violet
        Case "6"
            txt.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        Case "7"
            txt.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have to write them out manually. You can select multiple controls in the designer, open the Properties window, click the Events button and then double-click an event to generate a single event handler for that event of all the selected controls.  You can also use the drop-down for an event to select an existing handler to add one or more controls to the Handles clause of.

There are two ways to register event handlers in VB.  You can use `WithEvents` and `Handles`, which is what you're doing, in which case you must include every identifier in the code.  That means that you can't make that code shorter and use a `Handles` clause.  The alternative to a `Handles` clause is to use `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`.  That is usually done with controls created at run-time rather than design-time but you can do it for either.  In your case, you might add code like this to the `Load` event handler of the form:

```
Dim letters = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "H", "I"}

For Each letter In letters
    For n = 1 To 8
        AddHandler Controls($"txtDraw{letter}{n}").TextChanged, AddressOf TextBoxes_TextChanged
    Next
Next
```

You would do the same in the `FormClosed` event handler but with `RemoveHandler` instead of `AddHandler`.